# ubuntu gnome 14.04.2 - fonts broken

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I've a fresh install Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.2.
Randomly it happens that font gets broken (becomes unreadable) in terminal and also in gedit. Please note that, if I select the broken text (for example using the mouse to select the text) it becomes readable...but when the selection turns off the text become broken again. Unfortunately I cannot attach the broken text.

Any idea? How can I solve?

Tnx in advance for your helps.

Regards,
Simone.

Comment: Please note that if I close & reopen terminal/gedit fonts are ok.  Tnx.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the issue? (you can use https://imgur.com and [edit] the link into your post)

Comment: Could you make a screenshot? You can use a program like shutter to take a screenshot of a particular area.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded a terminal screenshot: [fontsBroken](http://postimg.org/image/x64arwc7f/). Please note that I have to logout/reboot in order to solve. Closing and reopening terminal/gedit/firefox does not solves. Tnx & regards.